# Issue with IP address

Tags: wifi

looking up

```
nslookup myhostname
```

results in

```
Server:     192.168.0.254
Address:    192.168.0.254#53

Name:   myhostname.home
Address: 192.168.0.16
Name:   myhostname.home
Address: 2a02:21b0:644d:ce87:a12c:7c61:dc14:d111
Name:   myhostname.home
Address: 2a02:21b0:644c:7l96:ad3a:2ecc:5e67:98f
```

This is not my WLAN connection! Also, I use no ethernet.

when I run

```
nslookup myhostname-1
```

my wlan shows up with IP 192.168.0.12 and myhostname-1.home (also only one ipv6 address)...

--> can anyone provide some feedback how to troubleshoot this so I can delete the 192.168.0.16 IP? When I set hostname, it affects that IP, not the other one (192.168.0.12) which is my wlan0...

I have been trying everything for several days now.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to delete something that you do not understand?

Comment: `with only one MAC address` you do realise there's no MAC addresses shown by nslookup ... those are IPv6 addresses (though, you mistyped the second one, `7l96` is invalid, perhaps you meant `7196`

Comment: @jsotola: (i) caps gone; (ii) I am kind of a noob re IP/DHCP - no idea how I get an IP address which is not wlan0 and is not eth0... very weird.

Comment: @Bravo: you are right - I anonymized the string as I (wrongly) thought it was MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching for the name of the device instead of "myhostname". (In the case that your device is not name "myhostname")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).